# How to use if statement in Panda Dataframe to copy images to a new directory?

Tags: python, pandas, image, dataframe, dataset

I tried to copy image to different directories using the "E" column of the dataframe. But my code copy every image to dir_0 and dir_1

The dataframe looks like this:

```
           A  C   D      E
0  english_0  0   0  False
1  english_1  1   2  False
2  english_2  2   4  False
3  english_3  3   6   True
4  english_4  4   8   True
5  english_5  5  10   True






src_dir = "/Users/Downloads/copy_image_test/source_dir"
dst_dir1 = "/Users/Downloads/copy_image_test/target_dir/1"
dst_dir0 = "/Users/Downloads/copy_image_test/target_dir/0"
def split_image_to_folder(row):

    for image in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.png")):
        if (row['E'] == 0):
            shutil.copy(image, dst_dir0)
        else:
            shutil.copy(image, dst_dir1)


df.apply(split_image_to_folder, axis = 1)
```

Comment: What have you tried (show us code, not just descriptions).  What conditions dictate whether the image is copied or not?  Do you just need to know how to move a file (see shutil.move)?  This is too vague to answer.

Comment: edited! i figure if processing a large amount of data, using dataframe si probably still the most time efficient way of doing it

Comment: You don't need  a dataframe to do this and I do not understand what you are doing here (maybe I should say I do not understand WHY you are doing certain things).  Every image will be copied to dst_dir0 AND des_dir1 because you are calling split_image_to_folder for every row of 'E' (i.e. both True and False) then iterating through every file within src_dir.  Since 'E' is False on the first call everything will go to dir0...then when 'E' is True on the third call everything gets copied to dir1.  In short, you are copying every file to each directory three times.